# how to get json posted data in the controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm working on a CodeIgniter project and I'm  newbie to ajax/jquery. I'm using fullCalendar. In my my view I want to post the date of an event and then post it to the controller. Here is my CalendarView.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {  
               add_event(date);
        },
        events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/myLogin%40gmail.com/public/basic'
    });
});

//Ajax call
function add_event(date) { 
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url()."/welcome/add_event/"; ?>',
                        data:{ eventsJson: JSON.stringify(date) },
                        dataType : "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
    });
}​
```

In my controller, here is what I do:

```
$date= $this->input->post('data');
```

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller to receive the `eventsJSON` you'd do:

```
$eventsJSON = json_decode($this->input->post('eventsJSON'), TRUE);
```

Now `$eventsJSON` contains an array with your json data.  However, if you're only sending back the date you don't need to pass it back as JSON, plus `eventsJSON` is a bad name for it.  In this case you could simply change the data part of the ajax call like:

```
data: 'date='+date,
```

And in your controller:

```
$date = $this->input->post('date');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about codelgnitor, but the data arrives in object form, you can retrieve the date string as $_POST['data']['eventsJson']

Though I don't think "eventsJson" is a very intuitive name, probably should be called "date" instead ;-)